# Remove hover event from circle in c3js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I want circles in my area chart not to have hover event.

As you can see in attached screenshots, when circle is hovered, it's changed. How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a option called `point`, just add that like this example at you're code and will hide them.

```
point: {
    show: false
}
```

as you mentioned want to hide only data on mouseover at point, here the code for that:

```
tooltip: {
    show: false,
    point: false,
},
```

and point will still scale on hover, you need to added also:

```
point: {
  focus: {
    expand: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  }
},
```

then should everything work just fine.

Comment: It removes point from my chart. I don't need to remove it, i just need remove hover action

Comment: @Grzegorzg, only want to remove the data on hover action, and point will still to scale a little bit.

Comment: @Grzegorzg, I've updated the answer, should hide the hover action at all now.

Comment: @Grzegorzg great.